# WP_query call triggers a error

Tags: php, wordpress

I've looked all over the theme, in plugins, I cannot figure out where ' is messing up.

WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%men\'s%') OR (ec_posts.post_content LIKE '%men\'s%')))  AND (ec_posts.post_pass' at line 2 for query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  ec_posts.ID FROM ec_posts  INNER JOIN ec_postmeta ON (ec_posts.ID = ec_postmeta.post_id)\nINNER JOIN ec_postmeta AS mt1 ON (ec_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND (((ec_posts.post_title LIKE '%men\') OR (post_excerpt LIKE '%men\'s%') OR (ec_posts.post_content LIKE '%men\'s%')))  AND (ec_posts.post_password = '')  AND ec_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (ec_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND ( (ec_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(ec_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search'))\nAND  (mt1.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'instock') ) GROUP BY ec_posts.ID ORDER BY ec_posts.menu_order,ec_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 48 /* From [domain.com/?s=men%27s&post_type=product] in [/nas/wp/www/cluster-1340/domain/index.php:17] */ made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, referer: http://domain.com/

I cannot find where this error is coming from.

Comment: I wish it was that easy pr1nc3 - it looks fine to me.

Comment: could you just paste your wp_query php code here ?